# Drupal edit a page

Tags: php, drupal

I'm usually working in Wordpress, so Drupal is a bit new to me.
So this is probably a noob question, but I've really been trying to figure this out for a while now.

So I need to edit a page and all I've got is the URL and login to the drupal-site with an admin account.

I can't find the page anywhere in the content tab.

There's no edit button when I'm logged in and go to the page.

Nothing happens when I go to URL/edit. It just looks the same.

And I still don't know what kind of content-type this page has.

I'm still awaiting the FTP login, but there still has to be any kind of trace on the drupal-login to create the link right? Thinking if it is a static page.

Can anyone help me where to even start?

**EDIT/ANSWER:**

It was a static page put in directly on the server, so there's no answer to this question.

Comment: You have an admin account or a normal user? If normal user, you have the proper permission to edit content items? Is Drupal 6 or 7?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I have a admin account. Where can I check which version it is?

Comment: The admin user can do everything in the system should not have any issues like this (on 6 or 7) as far i know. Check the version in `admin>> reports>> status`. You know if your site is behind any cache server (squid or varnish)?

Comment: Drupal 7.37. No clue about the case server, but that shouldn't be such an issue here right? Right now it's just about making editing work.

Comment: the fastest solution is to ping someone who knows drupal and do a screen share. U will fix it in 10 mins

Comment: Unsatisfyingly it was a static page on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer for drupal starter is watch some youtube video, understand how it works and play drupal around and know well of each functions in there.

There is a content type "Basic page", you create a page, before submit you can select menu on top of the save. you can create a link to navigation for your new page.

all articles all node.

after you create pages, you can edit at top-menu, find Content and it will list all title of your articles.

Drupal is different with wp, you need watch some video, to know each part and drupal is very good.

Comment: I have watched a bunch of videos, still not finding what I'm looking for. I've tried to go inside content >> filter on basic page, and still not finding the page I'm looking for.